# Reading environment variable via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I would like to read an environment variable called "[TF]MYVAR" via PowerShell. However the following syntax does not work:

```
$env:[TF]MYVAR
```

It yields the following error:

> Missing or invalid array index expression.

Also adding quitation marks (-> "$env:[TF]MYVAR") does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets are confusing the command line parser.  Try the alternate variable syntax:

```
${<variable name>}
```

See also `Get-Help about_Variables`.

As @PetSerAl notes below, due to how the command line parser deals with escaping square bracket characters, you'll need to do this:

```
${env:``[TF``]MYVAR}
```

You can also use [the native .Net methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx), which work without needing to be escaped:

```
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('[TF]MYVAR')
```

Comment: That will not work. It gets you the value of the variable called `env:[TF]MYVAR`, but we're looking for the value of the item `[TF]MYVAR` in the `Env:` drive. The least verbose thing I found that does that is `gc env:'\`[TF\`]MYVAR'`, but there ought to be something better.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The `${ }` syntax has multiple uses in PowerShell.  Please read [the `Get-Help` entry for `about_Variables` under the heading for variables with special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6#variable-names-that-include-special-characters).

Comment: @JeroenMostert To get value of variable `env:[TF]MYVAR` it need to be `${variable:env:[TF]MYVAR}`.

Comment: Opening a `cmd` shell and issuing `set [TF]MYVAR=3`, then executing `powershell` and typing `${env:[TF]MYVAR}` gives nothing. This is PowerShell 5.1, incidentally. @PetSerAl: well the plot thickens, because yes, that does read the variable, while apparently `${env:[TF]MYVAR}` reads... nothing at all.

Comment: @BaconBits It need to be ```${env:``[TF``]MYVAR}``` to work properly in that case.

Comment: @PetSerAl: you've cracked it. ...I really wouldn't have stumbled on that even *with* the documentation. I'm not saying it's the *least* intuitive thing ever, but it's close.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `${env:[TF]MYVAR}` is not read nothing. It read `TMYVAR` or `FMYVAR` environment variable.

Comment: @PetSerAl: ...this makes a perverted sort of sense, and explains why regular regex syntax will not work (it's passed as a file wildcard, so only things like `?` and `*` and `[...]` do stuff)... but ouch. The drive metaphor really doesn't work out very well for most things.

Comment: @PetSerAl Well, that is absurd.

Comment: This is certainly a good reason to not use symbols in environment variables!